# How to convert the data return from api into json in Angular?

Tags: angular, https, rest

```
userdata:any[];
    
this.auth.getapicall().subscribe(datareturn=>{
            console.log(datareturn.message);
            this.userdata=datareturn;
```

I am calling an api with get method and store its data in "datareturn". I have stored the result in array of userdata. if I console the userdata it returns the results but I am unable to understand that how to access the data inside userdata.
Here is the console data snapshot....

Here is console result

```
{data: Array(1), pageinfo: {…}, message: "Success", submessage: "Success"}
data: Array(1)
0: {id: "5fd881a754315ca43cf4af48", account_id: "5fce31a454315ca43cf4af31", user_id: "5fce31a454315ca43cf4af32", name: "aamaadmi", is_custom: true, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "Success"
pageinfo: {page: 1, limit: 25, total_count: 1}
submessage: "Success"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.userdata = datareturn.message?.data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console result shows only one array - the `data` property. So if the console log is resulted from logging `datareturn.message` then you can access your array with `datareturn.message?.data` like below -

```
this.auth.getapicall().subscribe(
    datareturn => {
        this.userdata = datareturn.message?.data;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If looking your api response it seems you are having three items

1. data
2. message
3. submessage

Your needed information is in data so you must code like

```
this.userdata = datareturn.data
```

Try this.